# Re-initializing random distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Is it reasonable to expect that a distribution from <random> re-initialized before each next number request behaves the same way as if it was initialized once? In other words, does this:

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
int p[10]={};
for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
 std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,9);
 int number = distribution(generator);
 ++p[number];
}
```

have the same distribution as that

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,9);
std::default_random_engine generator;
int p[10]={};
for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
 int number = distribution(generator);
 ++p[number];
}
```

I've checked that for uniform and normal distribution it empirically holds true. Can I expect it from every distribution in <random>?

Comment: I was reminded of a CppCon talk a few years ago that dealt with this same question; I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Related to [distributions-and-internal-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103356/distributions-and-internal-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I essentially do what your first implementation does. Construct one every time I need a distribution.

That said, yes, the behavior of the different distributions are [guaranteed by the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution) to behave in specific ways.

[STL recommends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY&t=30m), that since distributions are relatively cheap, don't worry about constructing one every time you need one or need a new range. He also says if you don't want to construct one every time, you can use the [param](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) member function to change the distribution range.

Microsoft Channel9 link if the above direct Youtube link dies (seek to 30 minutes in): https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

EDIT

I was re-watching a CppCon talk from a few years ago that discusses this exact question. The result? Constructing distributions as local variables *even inside loops* [is 4.5 *times* faster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_QO1nm7uJs&t=38m10s).

Comment: But distribution might have internal state.